# Getting the value of a $resource call in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm using AngularJS and I've made a $resource call to fetch a single value (e.g. the fetch gets me 14).

The following is in my controller:

```
var MaxCount = $resource('/maxquestion/fetch', null, 
{
    getMaxQuestionCount: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
});
$scope.maxQuestionCount = MaxCount.getMaxQuestionCount();
```

Now I'm trying to use `$scope.maxQuestionCount` in the controller, doing `$scope.maxQuestionCount[0]` gives me `1` and `$scope.maxQuestionCount[1]` gives me `4`

`console.log($scope.maxQuestionCount)` me `[object Object]`
 `console.dir($scope.maxQuestionCount)` me `There are no child objects`

I'm confused. How to access the value 14?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is really not much point in using `$resource` for data structures like those. The thing is that `$resource` works great for RESTful endpoint where all the HTTP verbs are used. To make this easy AngualarJS extends incoming objects with convenience methods ($save, $delete etc.). If you return primitives there is no room for extension and one of the major benefits of `$resource` is gone.

In short: if you are just after fetching data $resource is an overkill IMO, stick with the `$http` instead. The `$http` service, although considered to be lower-level as compared to `$resource` is very convenient and easy to use. Taking your example, you could write:

```
$http.get('/maxquestion/fetch').success(function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

Refer to the documentation for more examples: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll surely take that into consideration and rewrite the code I've written. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it. I've changed it to $http and it works now. Awesome